# Make all select elements in the table as disabled on a particular condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
            function checkifassigned(callno)
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'index.php?action=searchbookforassigningbarcode',
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        data: {callno:callno},
                        success: function(data){

                            if (data.length)
                            {
                                if(data[0]['DataAvail'] != 0)
                                {
                                   for(var i in data)
                                   { 
                                        var issuehistory = data[i]['issuehistory'];
                                        for(var j in issuehistory)
                                        {
                                            $('.library_info_tbl').find('select').each(function () {          
                                        
                                            var id = $(this.id);
                                           
                                            if (id ==  issuehistory[j]['acquisitionno']) 
                                            {
                                                  $(this).prop("disabled", true);            
                                            }
                                        
                                        });
                                        }
                                     }
                                  }
                               }
                            }
                        });
                    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="library_info_tbl">
        ...
        ...
          <td class="text-center centeralign"><div class="btn-group"><input type="text" class="hide" id="acquisitionno1" value="16">
          <select id="16" class="form-control"><option value="Select">Select</option><option value="Damaged">Damaged</option><option value="Lost">Lost</option></select></div></td>
                 ...
                 ...     
             <td class="text-center centeralign"><div class="btn-group"><input type="text" class="hide" id="acquisitionno1" value="16">
          <select id="17" class="form-control"><option value="Select">Select</option><option value="Damaged">Damaged</option><option value="Lost">Lost</option></select></div></td>
               ...
               ...
       </table>
```

I have a table in web page which contain select elements with specific id assigned to them as shown in the above html code.

Now I want to make all those select elements in the table as disabled if their id match with 'acquisitionno' in the loop.

The above jQuery code does not make the desired select elements disabled.

The data is:

```
           {
     "_id": ObjectId("59fff82b1d78594010000029"),
     "book_id": NumberInt(4),
     "bookadditionmode": "General",
     "callno": NumberInt(4),
     "isbn": "123456789",
     "title": "General Robotics Studies",
     "subject": "Robotics",
     ...

       "issuehistory": [
        {
          "student_id": NumberInt(2),
          "student_name": "Zulekha Fayaz",
          "issue_date": ISODate("2017-11-05T23:00:00.0Z"),
          "due_date": ISODate("2017-11-15T23:00:00.0Z"),
          "acquisitionno": NumberInt(16),
          "inserted_at": "11/06/2017 07:09:32",
          "inserted_by": NumberInt(1) 
        },
        {
          "student_id": NumberInt(3),
          "student_name": "Nazia Ahmad",
          "issue_date": ISODate("2017-11-05T23:00:00.0Z"),
          "due_date": ISODate("2017-11-15T23:00:00.0Z"),
          "acquisitionno": NumberInt(17),
          "inserted_at": "11/06/2017 07:09:32",
          "inserted_by": NumberInt(1) 
        }  
      ],
```

Comment: can you share the structure of `data`?

Comment: Also, what error do you see in the browser console?

Comment: Element ID's must be unique in a page by definition. Use a `data-` attribute instead. Provide a data sample as in [mcve]

Comment: yes they are already unique

Comment: OK well they weren't before the edit. Where's the data sample that reproduces problem?

Comment: updated my question

Comment: @Nida can you share the output of `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));`

Comment: That data sample isn't very informative regarding full structure but it appears you don't need the inner loop

Comment: What is the actual error?? Error messages are big clues that tell you a lot

Comment: Now I want to make all those select elements in the table as disabled if their id match with 'acquisitionno' in the loop. ==> Does this mean that if matches with select tag id or any element inside the <td> with that id. Also it is exact match or like condition

Comment: It does not throw any error message but the desired select element does not get disabled...

Comment: Ok but you stated there were syntax errors in question which is misleading

Comment: sorry for inconvience... please help me

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach would be map an array of `acquisitionno` first then filter selects based on values in that new array.

depending on what the data structure looks like it would look something like:

```
var acquisitionno = data.map(e=> e.issuehistory.acquisitionno)
$('table select').prop('disabled', function(){
   return acquisitionno.includes(this.id)
})
```

Above assumes data structure looks like:

```
[{
    issuehistory: {
      acquisitionno: 16
    }
  },
  {
    issuehistory: {
      acquisitionno: 17
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your ids are unique, then simply use this logic

```
if ( data.issuehistory )
{
    data.issuehistory.forEach( function( issuehistory ){
        $( "#" + issuehistory[ "acquisitionno" ] ).prop("disabled", true);    
    });
}
```

**Demo**

```js
var data = {
  "issuehistory": [{
      "acquisitionno": 16,
    },
    {
      "acquisitionno": 17,
    }
  ]
};
if (data.issuehistory) {
  data.issuehistory.forEach(function(issuehistory) {
    $("#" + issuehistory["acquisitionno"]).prop("disabled", true);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="library_info_tbl">
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center centeralign">
      <div class="btn-group"><input type="text" class="hide" id="acquisitionno1" value="16">
        <select id="16" class="form-control"><option value="Select">Select</option><option value="Damaged">Damaged</option><option value="Lost">Lost</option></select>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center centeralign">
      <div class="btn-group"><input type="text" class="hide" id="acquisitionno1" value="16">
        <select id="17" class="form-control"><option value="Select">Select</option><option value="Damaged">Damaged</option><option value="Lost">Lost</option></select>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @charlietfl yes, just realized it.

Comment: it is not making desired select elements disabled

Comment: @Nida It should, check the demo.

Comment: @Nida what doesn't work? Haven't I shared a working demo in my post?

Comment: this code is not making the desired select element disabled

Comment: @Nida Not sure what you mean since I can see that both `select` elements are disabled when I run the snippet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158325/discussion-between-nida-and-gurvinder372).